# icsc.begin(8, 57600, 18);

Tags: visual-c++, arduino-esp32

```
C:\Users\Desktop\LED\LED\LED.ino: In function 'void setup()':
C:\Users\Desktop\LED\LED\LED.ino:469:25: error: no matching function for call to 'ICSC::begin(int, int, int)'
   icsc.begin(8, 57600, 18);
                         ^
In file included from C:\Users\jharadillos\Desktop\LED\LED\LED.ino:1:
c:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ICSC\src/ICSC.h:189:14: note: candidate: 'void ICSC::begin()'
         void begin();
              ^~~~~
c:\Users\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ICSC\src/ICSC.h:189:14: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
```

exit status 1

Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'ICSC::begin(int, int, int)'

Sketch uses 267497 bytes (20%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 21652 bytes (6%) of dynamic memory, leaving 306028 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The library function `icsc.begin(8, 57600, 18);` you are calling expects **zero** arguments/parameters but you are trying to pass **three** arguments to it.

Instead of `icsc.begin(8, 57600, 18);`, call the function with `icsc.begin()`, or use a different library like this [ICSC Library](https://github.com/MD4N1/RS485-Data-Communicatiion-Demo/blob/master/Library/Arduino/ICSC).